# Core https library vs. npm 'request' library

Tags: node.js, https, request

I am running into a very strange issue when trying to use the built-in node https library.

Request Headers:

```
  let requestDetails = {
    hostname: 'api.domain.com',
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/endpointIWant/goHere
    headers: {
      'Client-ID': clientId,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: bearerToken
    },
  };
```

Request body:

```
 let body = JSON.stringify({
    "content_type": "application/json",
     "message" : message
  });
```

This is my standard call using the default https library of node:

```
 let req = https.request(requestDetails, function (res){

    let responseBody = undefined;

    res.on('body', function(res) {
      responseBody = '';
    });

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      responseBody += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log(responseBody);
    });
  });

  req.write(body);

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

  req.end();
```

Now whenever I send this request to the relevant server I get a:

```
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;24507368&#46;1554749705&#46;3185b29b
```

However when I use the popular 'request' library on NPM it works fine and I get the response I expect.

This leads be to believe there is something different in maybe the 'encoding' or 'chunking' of the requests between these two libraries, but I cannot figure out what.

Does anyone have experience with the Node https library and understand any gotcha's there?

I prefer to use built-in libraries as much as possible to keep my package size low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using native **http** or **https** modules, you need to use the querystring module to stringify your body.

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

let body = querystring.stringify({
    "content_type": "application/json",
    "message" : message
});

//also include the content length of your body as a header

let requestDetails = {
    hostname: 'api.domain.com',
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/endpointIWant/goHere
    headers: {
      'Client-ID': clientId,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length' : body.length
      Authorization: bearerToken
    },
  };
```

**'request'** is built on top of the native modules and does this internally when you pass it a json body

Comment: Thank you! I actually had done this before in previous implementations, but forgot to read my own notes.

Can you explain why it needs queryString vs. JSON.stringify?

Comment: unfortunately it didnt help. Even when doing this I still get issues with the server Im requesting from

Comment: I had to use this content-type in the header to get it to work do you know why: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

Comment: I am not sure. What kind of errors did you get after you made the querystring change but before you changed the content-type?